C# readability - async/await or return for wrapping asynchronous functions?
Say I have an asynchronous method:
public async Task DoThing(int x)
{
    // ...
}

Now, I want to wrap this method with a new method. Each of these two options are functionally equivalent:
public async Task WrapperOne()
{
    await DoThing(6);
}

public Task WrapperTwo()
{
    return DoThing(6);
}

This is because C# treats a Task just like any other object, so it can be passed through, returned, and so on as any object can. In fact, I presume these two methods compile to the same thing (please correct me if this premise is wrong). My question is, from a code readability perspective, which is better? I was not able to find any official guidance about this on Microsoft, but maybe I missed it?

How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?

await affects the flow of the program;  perhaps one way you could visualise it would be to modify DoThing to throw an exception and then catch both exceptions in main - you'll see a very clear difference between the two stack traces.

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

This is very helpful @null - Would you make this an answer?


This is a surprisingly nuanced question, and in fact I now hold to a different answer than the position I originally took on this issue.

Says Stephen Cleary about this issue in Eliding Async and Await, which goes to show that opinions about this issue might have changed over time. He continues describing pitfalls with Using, Exceptions and AsyncLocal concluding

Recommended Guidelines
I suggest following these guidelines:

Do not elide by default. Use the async and await for natural, easy-to-read code.
Do consider eliding when the method is just a passthrough or overload.

Examples:
// Simple passthrough to next layer: elide.
Task<string> PassthroughAsync(int x) => _service.PassthroughAsync(x);

// Simple overloads for a method: elide.
async Task<string> OverloadsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ... // Core implementation, using await.
}
Task<string> OverloadsAsync() => OverloadsAsync(CancellationToken.None);

// Non-trivial passthrough: use keywords.
async Task<string> PassthroughAsync(int x)
{
    // Reasoning: GetFirstArgument can throw.
    //  Even if it doesn't throw today, some yahoo can change it tomorrow, and it's not possible for them to know to change *this* method, too.
    return await _service.PassthroughAsync(GetFirstArgument(), x);
}

// Non-trivial overloads for a method: use keywords.
async Task<string> OverloadsAsync()
{
    // Same reasoning as above; GetDefaultCancellationTokenForThisScope can throw.
    return await OverloadsAsync(GetDefaultCancellationTokenForThisScope());
}


According to David Fowler you should Prefer async/await over directly returning Task because

There are benefits to using the async/await keyword instead of directly returning the Task:

Asynchronous and synchronous exceptions are normalized to always be asynchronous.
The code is easier to modify (consider adding a using, for example).
Diagnostics of asynchronous methods are easier (debugging hangs etc).
Exceptions thrown will be automatically wrapped in the returned Task instead of surprising the caller with an actual exception.
Async locals will not leak out of async methods. If you set an async local in a non-async method, it will "leak" out of that call.



NOTE: There are performance considerations when using an async state machine over directly returning the Task. It's always faster to directly return the Task since it does less work but you end up changing the behavior and potentially losing some of the benefits of the async state machine.

In Do not await what does not need to be awaited Jiří Činčura performs some benchmarks, the more realistic one being:

I tested a call where some callback really happens. I used Task.Delay(1), thus don’t look at absolute numbers, but only at the difference.



Method
Mean
Error
StdDev
Scaled
Allocated




WithoutAwait
15.62 ms
0.0085 ms
0.0079 ms
1.00
312 B


WithAwait
15.62 ms
0.0096 ms
0.0089 ms
1.00
528 B



The execution speed here is the same because the execution itself is fully overruled by the duration of the asynchronous method itself (in this case the timer callback), as it should be. But there’s a 216 bytes difference in allocation (.NET Core 2.0.3, 64-bit RyuJIT). Does it matter? In normal code probably not. But why to give something out when the “fix” is super easy and clean.
Summary
Was this just my rambling about a problem that in real world doesn’t matter that much? Yes, it was.


These two functions are not exactly equivalent
I'm going to get in the weeds a bit here, but these two functions are only mostly equivalent.
In C#, Tasks are not the only thing which can be awaited. You can await anything which has a GetAwaiter method (or extension method), and where the return type of that method implements the Awaiter pattern. Tasks implement this pattern, but so can other things.
Thus, the first option - an async method which awaits the underlying DoThing will still compile even if DoThing is changed to a different kind of awaitable. The second option, meanwhile, requires that DoThing return an object which is assignable to Task, and will fail to compile otherwise.
This sort of wrapping can be meaningful because await's duck-typing clashes with C#'s otherwise strongly typed nature - you cannot create a List of awaitables, because awaitable is not a type. Thus, having a method which can convert another kind of awaitable into a task can be necessary in order to take advantage of methods like Task.WhenAll over custom awaiters.
For the same, if these two methods do compile to the identical bytecode, it would be because of an optimization made by the compiler. The code describes two different operations: One says to create a task which wraps the awaiting of some underlying work, while the other simply passes through to another method.
In terms of maintainability, I would prefer WrapperOne
I see WrapperOne as being easier to change in the future, while WrapperTwo can only do exactly what it does now.

If a change requires it to do additional work, a second line can be added to await DoOtherThing(), while WrapperTwo would not support this.
If a change requires that the way the await context be configured, it could change to something like await DoThing(6).ConfigureAwait(false). To do the same for WrapperTwo would require changing its method signature.
If a change modifies DoThing to be an awaitable object other than a Task, WrapperOne will require no changes, while WrapperTwo would require a change to its method signature.
Lastly, as a matter of personal preference, I believe that non-async methods which behave like async ones should be minimized. Stylistically, developers (in my experience) don't like to think about Tasks as objects, and would rather think of DoThing as a void method which needs to be awaited, rather than as a method which returns a Task. Exposure to the details of how await is implemented should be minimized.


Thanks for your answer! It's an interesting point about the "awaitable" idea - I would think that you could make a List of IAwaitables or something like that, but it's not particularly relevant to my use case where everything is a Task or Task<SomeType>. Is there unnecessary overhead involved in creating a Task rather than just passing through?

@AAM111 - There would be overhead in the program described by the code, however, the compiler in Release mode might be smart enough to rewrite the program to avoid that overhead.

That said, I believe that that (linguistic) overhead adds value to justify itself. I've added a section to my answer explaining why WrapperOne is a more flexible construct.

Also worth mentioning that with WrapperTwo if DoThing throws an Exception you won't have the call to DoThing in your stacktrace

pretty sure ive experienced differences in api controllers with return await and return
